# Global variable of String type

Tags: java

I have the following global variable of String type.

```
static public String rev="hello"
```

I can read it without any issue from an object of another class. Is there anyway I can update it with another string from an object of another class?  I know Java string is immutable. I tried with the following way using StringBuilder:

```
  static public StringBuilder rev=new StringBuilder("hello");
  static public void setRev(StringBuilder s)
  {
    rev=rev.delete(0,rev.length());
    rev.append(s);
  }
```

From another class:

```
MainActivity.setRev(stringBuilderVar);
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Java String values are immutable. StringBuilders aren't.

Comment: Strings are immutable, but you can reassign a string _variable_ to a different string.  But you've earlier used `rev` (say `someOtherVar = MainActivity.rev`), reassigning `rev` won't change anything where you previously copied the reference.  Without more information, it's hard to tell what the right way to do things is.  But I'm pretty sure that `StringBuilder` is the wrong solution.

Comment: Declaring StringBuilder as static might be the cause of immutability? The reason I declare as static is that I am access from another class.

Comment: No, `static` has nothing to do with immutability.  `static` means that the variable belongs to the whole class and not to instances of the class.  And you can access non-static variables from another class by creating objects of the class, which is the normal way to do things.  I strongly suggest you work through a tutorial on Object-Oriented Programming concepts in Java, such as https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/.

Comment: Nobody gave any solution. It is very simple task for procedural languages. But for Java? And someone gave me -1 even without offering solution?

Comment: Figured it out. Java does not allow to use global var from a service which runs as a separate process.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for updating a field is the same for static and non-static fields. Simply use an assignment statement:

```
class Global {
    public static String greeting;
}

public class Other {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String newGreeting = "hello";
        Global.greeting = newGreeting;
    }
}
```

That said, once your programs get bigger, you'll likely want to use non-static fields instead.

Comment: The following is not working: Global.greeting=anotherStringVar;